# Why does my print statement in line 8 not run?

Tags: python, printing, tic-tac-toe

So I have made a code for a tic-tac-toe game (with a little help from udemy). I have some problems with it, but the one that has become most annoying for me, is the fact that I cannot put in a print statement anywhere.
I tried just typing:
print (turn + "will go first")
When this did nothing, I tried making an if-loop, so the statement will print out, but it doesn't print out.

I also wanted to print out whose turn it was, so after the:
if turn == "player 1"
I tried writing:
print ("player 1's turn: ")
and the same for player 2.
This didn't work either.

I realize there is a lot of code (all the functions that I have made) that you cannot see, but I dont see why that should stop a print-statement from executing.
this is my code:

```
print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')
while True:
    player1marker , player2marker = player_input()
    turn = choose_first()
    TheBoard = [" "] * 10
    **aaa = True
    if aaa:
        print(turn + " will go first")
        aaa = False**
    game_on = True
    while game_on:
        if turn == "player 1":
            display_board(TheBoard)
            position = player_choice(TheBoard)
            place_marker(TheBoard, player1marker, position)

            if win_check(TheBoard,player1marker):
                display_board(TheBoard)
                print ("gz player 1 you fucking smashed him")
                game_on = False
                break
            else: 
                if full_board_check(TheBoard):
                    display_board(TheBoard)
                    print ("it was a draw")
                    game_on = False
                    break
                else:
                    turn = "player 2"

        else:
            display_board(TheBoard)
            position = player_choice(TheBoard)
            place_marker(TheBoard, player2marker, position)
            if win_check(TheBoard,player2marker):
                display_board(TheBoard)
                print ("gz player 2 you fucking beat his ass")
                game_on = False
                break
            else: 
                if full_board_check(TheBoard) == True:
                    display_board(TheBoard)
                    print ("it was a draw")

                    game_on = False
                    break

                else:
                    turn = "player 1"
    if not replay():
        break
```

Comment: Because `aaa` is not `True`, `None` or is an empty variable.

Comment: But why doesn't it work when I leave the aaa out, and just print the statement?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `**`s from your code, they aren't necessary and are causing errors.

`**aaa` is not the same as `aaa`

Comment: yea, no it's not that. I put it there to make the text bold, and then I decided to remove it but forgot the opening.
It wasn't part of my code.